# bool - 255 value

Tags: c

I have this function defined:

```
struct heap_validation {
    size_t num_alloc;
    size_t num_alloc_sz;
    struct memory *mem;
};
...
bool get_isallocated(struct metadata_record *);
```

When I call the heap_validation function from hashtable_traverse and print the result, I've gotten the following values: 0,255 ,246

```
void hashtable_traverse(struct metadata_record *metarec,
        struct heap_validation *heap_val) {

    printf("get_isallocated(metarec): %d\n",get_isallocated(metarec));

    bool retrieved = false;
    bool allocated = get_isallocated(metarec);
    if (allocated) {
        heap_val->num_alloc += 1;
```

I also tried with %d and I get the same result.

Comment: It would help if you showed the definition of get_isallocated instead of just the declaration.

Comment: Are you getting the definition of `bool` from `#include <stdbool.h>`? If not, where is it coming from?

Comment: Found the issue, I'm posting the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the function **`hashtable_traverse`**, which is the function called by the *GLib's* `g_hash_table_foreach()` to iterate over a *GHashTable*, expects both the **key** and **value**.

I only had the value and a pointer to user data.

- `metarec` is the **value**.
- The **key** should be an address pointer (1st parameter), and `heap_val` is user data, which is optional in `g_hash_table_foreach()`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not include `<stdbool.h>` then `bool` isn't guaranteed to be `_Bool`.

In C++ (§4.5/4), when a value is converted to `bool`, it becomes a 0 or a 1:

> An rvalue of type bool can be converted to an rvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

In C (§6.3.1.2/1), when a value is converted to _Bool, it becomes 0 or 1:

> When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.

If you're getting values besides zero and one, then `bool` is not `_Bool` and `get_isallocated()` is returning a value besides zero or one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  _Bool x=69;
  printf("x=%d\n",x);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

will print out `x=1`.

Comment: `bool` is very much a part of the C99 standard, if the header file `<stdbool.h>` is included.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correct,then perhaps you want boolean output:-

```
printf("get_isallocated(metarec): %d\n",get_isallocated(metarec)!=0);
```

or

```
printf("get_isallocated(metarec): %s\n",get_isallocated(metarec)!=0?"True":"False");
```

It will output a `0` or `1` .

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it prints out 1 or 255, both are evaluated as the boolean true.

Comment: @user1655481, yes I was looking for the boolean input and output.  I found the problem, which I'm posting below.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the value `0` or `1` from `stdbool.h` `bool` type.

If it is not the case, either your program (probably `get_isallocated` function) is invoking undefined behavior or your are not using `bool` from `stdbool.h` but an alias to another standard integer type.